# Multiple File Upload With Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

```
'Unexpected field 'img.0.error' in POST data, Unexpected field 'img.0.name' in POST  
Cake\Controller\Exception\AuthSecurityException
```

Comment: There is no question and no code in what you posted.

Comment: Since this keeps coming up in the H&I queue, I made an edit to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from the [Security Component](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html). You will likely need to either unlock the img field, or else disable the security component entirely for this action. Specifics of how to do this may vary depending on your specific version, so check the linked manual for implementation details.